# Getting uninitialized constant error when trying to instantiate a new class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, subclass

I'm receiving an error:

```
lynda.rb:206:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Pig (NameError)
```

when I try to instantiate a new instance of the pig class. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? I have searched online and I've been told it is commonly due to not requiring your parent class properly. However my parent class is within the same file.

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_writer :colour
  attr_reader :legs, :arms

 def initialize(noise,legs=4,arms=0)
    @noise = noise
    @legs = legs
    @arms = arms

    puts "A new animal has been instantiated"
 end

 def noise=(noise)
    @noise = noise
 end

 def noise
    @noise
 end



  class Pig < Animal
   def noise
      parent_method = super
      puts "Hello and #{parent_method}"
   end
 end

  class Cow < Animal
  end
end

piggy = Pig.new("oink")
p piggy.noise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `Pig` class inside `Animal` class.

In spite of the fact, that it is most likely not what you intended it to be, to solve the problem you'd want to reference the class correctly:

```
piggy = Animal::Pig.new("oink")
```

Define the `Pig` and `Cow` classes outside of `Animal` class, meaning, close the `Animal` class before opening the `Pig`. This way you'll be able to instantiate it with:

```
 piggy = Pig.new("oink")
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I've tried both ways. Thank you, I never realized Ruby doesn't know where to find the Pig subclass if you don't specify. Much appreciated.

Comment: Jack, it's not so much about not knowing where to find subclasses; the subclass issue is a red herring. It's that you've _contained_ your Pig class _inside_ the Animal class (and I mean the _class_, not the file); you'd have run into the same problem even if Pig was not a subclass of Animal, simply because you opened Pig before closing Animal.